# Hibernate Envers - Doesn't write audit records for createQuery(...).executeUpdate(), only .persist() and .merge()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jboss, hibernate-envers

I have 3 ways things get written to the DB

```
public void create(T object) {
    entityManager.persist(object);
}

public void update(T object) {
    object = entityManager.merge(object);
}

public int updateStatus(String id, String status) {

    final int changes =
                entityManager.createQuery("update item set state = :newState," +
                        " last_modified = current_timestamp" +
                        " where id = : id ")
                    .setParameter("newState", status)
                    .setParameter("id", id)
                    .executeUpdate();

            return changes;
}
```

The problem I have, is in order to get the Hibernate Envers to actually write the audit records to the corrsponsing x_aud and revinfo DB tables. It only works successfully for '.persist()' or '.merge()'. I cannot get it to work for 'createQuery(...)**.executeUpdate()**'

Am I missing something or does it just not work for this. The problem is, a lot of my code has been written using .executeUpdate and not merge, so really I need this to work with the existing code.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: is it a SQL query or HQL Query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like **Avinash T.** is right - if you want to create native SQL query, use `createNativeQuery(String sqlString)` method of `EntityManager`. Using `createQuery(String ejbqlString)` is only possible if you're using EJB QL. Hope it would help.

Comment: I am not using native sql query, insteas using HQL only. But the auditing on .executeUpdate() doesn't works. Is there any way you achieved this.

Answer (score 10):

No, Envers won't work if you are using executeUpdate. That is because the update doesn't pass through Hibernate's event mechanism, so Envers has no chances of intercepting the change, and writing the audit.

Comment: If I write a Spring data jpa query for update ,will enver be able to intercept it ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this -

```
    public int updateStatus(String id, String status) {

    final int changes =
                entityManager.createQuery("Update Item set state = :newState," +
                        " lastModified = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" +
                        " where id = : id ")
                    .setParameter("newState", status)
                    .setParameter("id", id)
                    .executeUpdate();

            return changes;
}
```

Following link wiil help you to learn more about JPQL -

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbtg.html

Answer (score 0):

I also needed to update a single field of my entity. If you don't need to directly use the `EntityManager`, in my case a solution for Envers to be aware of the entity-state change was to annotate my `@Entity` class with `@DynamicUpdate`, and wrap with `@Transactional` the method that set the field I wanted to update.

See this answer: [Update single field using spring data jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50297862/13467124)

Hibernate code that checks the `@DynamicUpdate` annotation:
org.hibernate.persister.entity.mutation.UpdateCoordinatorStandard#coordinateUpdate

But be aware that using `@DynamicUpate` might incur some performance costs:

> Specifies that SQL update statements for the annotated entity are
> generated dynamically, and only include columns which are actually
> being updated. This might result in improved performance if it is
> common to change only some of the attributes of the entity. However,
> there is a cost associated with generating the SQL at runtime